# What methods are executed in which order in this ASP.NET webforms page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was refactoring some old website the other day and stumbled upon this scenario. I have an ASP.NET 3.5 C# WebForms page. In the code behind I have an event handler like so:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) { }
```

On the other hand, in the markup, I also have:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    void Page_PreRender()
    {

    }
</script>
```

Question is: **what does the lifecycle look like? What is executed first? Is one of them even executed?**

Comment: If you have both, only the OnPreRender method in code behind will be invoked. Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points upfront:

- The `OnPreRender` method is not an event handler. It is an override of the method `Page.OnPreRender` (which is the method that will raise the `PreRender` event).
- The method `Page_PreRender` is automatically wired-up to the `PreRender` event. So this is an event handler (for the `PreRender` event).

**Order of invocation**

The following code sample shows the order of execution:

```
// code-behind
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    // 1. code put here will be executed first

    // now we call the base class' version, which will then raise the
    // PreRender event
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    // 3. code put here will be executed last
}

// markup       
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    void Page_PreRender()
    {
        // 2. code put here will be executed second
    }
</script>
```

Note that inside `OnPreRender()` the base class is invoked: `base.OnPreRender()`. As written above, if this is missing then the `PreRender`event will not be raised and event handlers will therefore not be called.

**Your code sample**

In your sample code, the call to `base.OnPreRender` is missing. This means, that `PreRender` event is not raised and therefore the (event handler) method `Page_PreRender()` will not be called.

**Some more points to consider**

- If you have a `Page_PreRender()` event handler in your markup and in your code-behind, then only the one in the code-behind will be called.
- If you disable the auto-wiring of events in the Page directive (e.g. `< % @ Page AutoEventWireup="false" ... % >`), then the `Page_PreRender()` event handler will not be wired/connected with the `PreRender` event and will  therefore not be called.
- You can also manually attach handlers to events, e.g:

---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     PreRender += PreRenderEventHandler;
 }
 void PreRenderEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer. It cleared it all up for me :) Essentially, I do have base.OnPreRender method call, I just removed it while pasting the code here. I didn't know it has such an important role in this context. reason I wanted this cleared up is because I wanted to move all C# to the code behind file and wasn't sure what the order would be like, but now I know what to do :)